# Parallax mapping better approximation of displacement UVs

Tags: parallax, polynomials, heightmap

Hey I have a question about finding the offset UVs regarding parallax mapping.

I read about the topic in the following article:
https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Parallax-Mapping

I see techniques about approximating the offset to the supposedly perceived point (`B`) in tangent space:
[image]
[image]

All the techniques describes ways to approximate the offset so we can't get perfect offset.
There're techniques for better approximations as seen in the article like steep parallax mapping or parallax occlusion mapping.

I thought of another way that can work maybe and give also good (maybe better?) results.
Maybe I'm talking nonsense but since I'm not a math person so take everything I say with a grain of salt and hopefully there's some sense in what I'm thinking. If not then you can educate me and that's fine.

Similar to steep parallax mapping we can sample the height map at several intervals (the more the better) store the heights of the height map in some kind of array and then with the given set of points we can solve the system of linear equation with polynomial interpolation with coefficients `aₖ`  where `K` equals to the number of layers we're sampling. Then with the function approximating the heightmap in the view direction area we can find the intersection point with the view direction to find UVs of point `B`.

Is it valid, can it work, if so will it be better approximation of previous methods? Would like to hear your thoughts. Probably it's just nonsense but would love to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have been thinking about this for some time now. They way I understand your idea, you would sample the heightmap at several intervals. That basically quantizes the part of the height map that is of interest at diskrete, equispaced height levels. Already this seems to be more work than just sampling it at just the single points after every ray step in steep parallax mapping.

Then in a second step, you suggest to basically fit a curve through those sampled points, right? Not sure if I got you right on this one. Now, getting this reconstructed ridge-line is the hard part. After that, finding all the intesection points with the viewing ray is easy and selection the one closest to the camera also.

I think for the results to be visually better, you should evaluate, if the reconstructed height profile is better if done through this linear equation reconstruction, or through the use of the texture sampled reconstruction. Which basically is a bilinear interpolation of values on a regular discrete grid.

Also, think about whether fitting a line through the sampled points yields consistend result for viewing rays that are close together. otherwise their could be jaggies or gaps.

If you ever get to trying this out, I would love to hear about your results!

Best of Luck!

- ADN